# Allow null values- input type number (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, keypress

I have the following code.

```
<input ng-keypress="onlyNumbers($event)" min="0" type="number" step="1" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,8}$/" ng-model="... >
```

Now it accepts only numerical values. I want null values to be accepted too. Since there are null values in database, i want it to reflect in the UI. currently i get [Object][Object] at the input for null value.

```
$scope.onlyNumbers = function(event){   
  var keys = {
    'up': 38,
    // Other key codes
    ...
    '9':57
  };

  for(var index in keys) {
    if (!keys.hasOwnProperty(index)) continue;
    if (event.charCode==keys[index]||event.keyCode==keys[index]) {
      return; //default event
    }
  }

  event.preventDefault();
};
```

Can anyone let me know how to make it work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What if you remove the `min` attribute and modified the ng-pattern to check for an empty input?

```
<input ng-keypress="onlyNumbers($event)" type="number" step="1" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,8}$|^$/" ng-model="... >
```

Comment: wat is the ng-pattern for empty input over here ?

Comment: The addition of `|^$` will add a second match possibility to the regex, where `^$` is basically saying match on the beginning of the, followed immediately by the end of line, and the `|` is of course just "or".

Comment: i wil try this code out and update if it works. thanks for the inputs n explaination

Comment: sorry. yes, it did work. accepted it as an answer. thanks for the answer

Comment: @mikesigs-  can you also let me know how to include a '.' in the ng-pattern as a accepted decimal. currently this ng-pattern doesnot allow me to type '.'

Comment: Can you provide some samples of valid input?

Comment: it should accept '-2.5', '-0.005', '2.5'. It shoud not accept '-2.-5', '-0..25'.

Comment: Try this /^[+-]?(?:\d+\.?\d*|\d*\.?\d+)[\r\n]*$|^$/. Also, download Expresso.